# Using inputtype date with handlebars --> hapi - handler

Tags: node.js, date, handlebars.js, hapi.js

Is there a way to send the selected date with

```
<input type="date" value="{{moment date=d format='YYYY-MM-DD'}}"/>
```

to the handler using hapi/ handlebars?
i'm trying to use two `datepickers` to define when to get records I view.

ex. https://someadress.com/applicants/from/timestamp(from)/to/timestamp(to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to fill in the datepicker values with the parameters in the url, you can set up a route like this, making sure to pass the dates in your context object.

```
const joi = require('joi');

const yourRoute = {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/applicants/from/{datefrom}/to/{dateto}',
    config: {
        validate: {
            params: {
                datefrom: joi.date(),
                dateto: joi.date()
            }
        }
    },
    handler: (request, reply) => {
        let context = {
            datefrom: request.params.datefrom,
            dateto: request.params.dateto
        };

        reply.view('path/to/view', context);
    }
};
```

And then in your template, you only need to set datefrom and dateto:

`<input type="date" value="{{datefrom}}"/>`

And in this example, moment isn't required on on the server. As long as the url parameters are in the correct format, [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) will handle parsing the date correctly for you.